# how to create an array for the settings (Obj C)?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I would like to be inspired by an application to create a table with settings for my application. But I do not know how to use the charts in Objective C. 
Can someone help me please? 
There are pictures to help you see the interface.

**Settings Tab 1**

[image: Settings tab]

**SettingsTab 2**

[image: Settings tab 2]

Comment: Are you going to group setting options?

Comment: I do not know yet. What do you recommend ?

Comment: can you suggest a solution, or give me a website that explains what I want? thanks

Comment: Your question is a bit unclear, I just made a guess on your supplied images.

Comment: Again, do you want to make your Settings view exactly the same as the images you just posted here?

Comment: Yes I wish exactly the same thing. If it's possible

Comment: Yes, you can. I am making a quick example for you.

Comment: Thank you very much it is very nice. If you want I can give you my email address and send it to me by mail, if you wish.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a very quick example demonstrate how to make a table view look exactly the same as your images:

First, let design our UI:
[image]

1. Set `Style` of `UITableView` to `Grouped`
2. Set `Prototype Cells` value to 1, drag an `UIImageView` & `UILabel` to newly added prototype cell, then set appropriate constraints as you wish.
3. Let assign `Cell Icon` with a value of `100` in its `tag` attribute & do the same but `101` for `Cell Title`
4. Create `dataSource` & `delegate` outlets for your `UITableView`

Now, back to coding stuff.
Tell your view to implement `UITableView`'s delegates:

```
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
@end
```

Then implement appropriate delegates:

```
@implementation ViewController {
    NSArray *images;
    NSArray *titles;
    NSArray *sections;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    images = @[@"history", @"profile", @"quote", @"search", @"post_count", @"star"];
    titles = @[@"General", @"Format", @"Unit", @"Import/Export", @"Update", @"Support"];
    sections = @[@"Preferences", @"Data", @""];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return 3;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return 2;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIImageView *imageView = [cell viewWithTag:100];
    UILabel *label = [cell viewWithTag:101];

    int index = (int)(indexPath.item + (indexPath.section * 2));
    imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[images objectAtIndex:index]];
    label.text = [titles objectAtIndex:index];

    return cell;
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    return [sections objectAtIndex:section];
}

-(NSString *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView titleForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
    if (section == 2) {
        return @"This is the section's footer title\nCoded by RyanB@StackOverflow";
    }

    return nil;
}
```

All done. Now build the project & run it to see the result.
[image]